# Displaying floating-point number as a percentage without changing the value of the number

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

Is it possible to specify `string.Format()` parameters to add percentage symbol without changing the value of the number?

Example:
We have the number `44.36` and we want to show in a grid and output to Excel as `"44.36%"`.  Dividing the value by `100` and then apply the `"P"` format is not an option. Changing the values can not be done in this case, we need to do it only by changing the `DisplayFormat` value.  Using `string.Format("{0}%", valueParam)` is not an option either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify a custom format.  You'll need to escape the percent sign `'%'` with a literal backslash `'\\'` so it doesn't reinterpret the value as a percentage.

```
var number = 44.36m;
var formatted = number.ToString("0.##\\%"); // "44.36%"
// format string @"0.##\%" works too

// using String.Format()
var sformatted = String.Format("{0:0.##\\%}", number); // "44.36%"
```